# Calculate how many holes in a line, when line length, hole and gap length are known.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a hand rail, that has regularly spaced holes in it. The rail length is given, the length of the holes is given, and the even gap between the holes is given. Also this run is positioned centrally in the handrail, in so much as the remaining gap is divided equally at the ends

I would like assistance with coming up with a formula that can calculate how many holes would fit in a given hand rail.

The purpose being that I were to tweak the variable lengths, the amount of holes is always calculated.

Here is a demonstration:

Rail length: 110  Hole Length: 10  Gap length: 5  End lengths 20 Amount of holes: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if, in your example, you could have 6 holes, which makes for 60 units of hole-length, 25 units of gap, and 12.5 end length, or even 7 holes, making 70 units of hole-length, 30 of gap, and 5 at each end. If you give us rail length, hole length, and gap, all three answers are valid. No single formula could possibly give all three.

But if you're willing to give the end length as well, then you have this:
\begin{align}
L = nh + (n-1)g + 2e
\end{align}
where $L$ is the total length, $n$ the number of holes, $h$ the hole-width, $g$ the gap between holes, and $e$ then end-length. Solving for $n$, we get
\begin{align}
L &= nh + (n-1)g + 2e\\
L -2e&= nh + ng-g\\
L -2e + g &= n(h + g)\\
\frac{L - 2e + g}{h+g} &= n,
\end{align}
and that's your formula. Of course, if you make the end-lengths too long, you can get negative values for $n$, but think of a 10-foot rail with two 7-foot end-lengths. Not much room for holes, is there?